# angular-sanitize.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
  $scope.searchCat = function(){
        $scope.searchArray = [];

        $scope.searchTerm = $('#search input[type="search"]').val().toLowerCase();
    }
```

```html
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
      <div class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" name="search" ng-model="searchTerm" style="width: 75%;margin-left:10px;" ng-change="searchCat()" placeholder="search for service"/>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
```

I am trying to use search in my list to get search item into lower case for next comparison i use toLowercase but i got type error as can not read property 'toLowercase' of undefined.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks..I tried with change in ng-model="searchValue" because i already use searchTerm to initilize lowercase value  and then tried into js file as   $scope.searchTerm = $scope.searchValue.toLowerCase(); but it gives same error

Answer (score 1):

When you do this: `ng-model="searchTerm"` in your html, you are declaring the two way data-binding to $scope.searchTerm. This means you never need to search for the dom-element.

```
// In the old days using jQuery you do this: 
$('#search input[type="search"]') // But never (seldom) with angular. Ugly as sin.
```

Instead:

```
// The binding is already there.
// Just set the value to something so it won't be undefined.
$scope.searchTerm = ""; 

$scope.searchCat = function(){
    // Or you could do an undefined check:
    if ( !angular.isUndefined($scope.searchTerm) ){
        $scope.searchTerm = $searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Of course this only converts it to lowercase. But we can't know what you want `$scope.searchArray` for. Explain further.

Comment: Thank you..this solution worked for me and i was declared $scope.searchArray for next comparision operation sorry by mistake it was attached in code